# load href into a div with jquery.on

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

how can i change the jquery load function to load a php page into a div with jquery.on
now i load diferents php pages into a "modal" div using .load but diferent php pages call jqueryui datepicker and when i change the content into the div datepicker function stops working. i think that the problem is in .load function then i think if i change it to .on method it will work, but i don't know how can i use the .on method to load a href into a div

```
//$("#flotante").fadeIn(1000).load(href); // load content into the div  


$("#flotante").on( 'load' , function() // i want to load with .on method
{

});
```

Comment: That's an event handler, it doesn't really load anything ?

Comment: no using .on doesn't load anything, but if i use .load it load the content. the problem is if i click into a href the "#flotante div" load the content in these content i have a form wich contents a datepicker jqueryui, now if i close the '#flotante div' and i choose other href wich contents other form wich contents other datepicker, the event datepicker not work the second time. i have been reading that the problem is .load function and i think that i use .on function can solve the problem, but i dont know how to load a href into the div with .on function

Answer (score 0):

Jquery .load function is not same as the .on load event. You need the following:

```
$("#flotante").on( 'load' , function() // i want to load with .on method
{

$.ajax({url : 'index.php', type : "get", dataType : "html" , success : function(data){
         $("#flotante").html(data);
}});

});
```